# Regex pattern for Australian Driving License Validation

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex pattern for Australian driver's license validation.

The criteria for the license are:

- Eight-, nine-, or 10-digit number, or a six-digit alphanumeric pattern that matches the Australia Driver's license number format. It also checks for common test numbers, and requires the presence of related keywords.
- Patterns:

  ```
  \d\d\d \d\d\d \d\d\d

  \d\d \d\d\d \d\d\d

  [A-Za-z]\d\d\d\d\d

  \d\d\d[-]\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d
  ```
- Data ending with any of the following list of values is not matched: 00000, 11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999

Regex I've come up with so far:

*For only numeric patterns
`[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}`

- not able to use negate case for data ending in repeating characters:

  ```
  ^(([0-9]){4}\1+$)
  ```

Can someone help coming up with regex that matches ALL of the above criteria (inclusion and exclusion case)? I'm confused how how account for 6 digit alphanumeric or 6-10 digits numeric with "-" in between. Also I was able to figure out how to determine repeating characters in the end with pattern:

```
(([0-9]){4}\1+$)
```

but not how to write regex to not match them. I tried `^(([0-9]){4}\1+$)` but that did not work.

Comment: *"and requires the presence of related keywords."*: I don't think you have given specs for that.

Comment: What flavor of RegExp are you working with?

Comment: "*Data ending with any of the following list of values is not matched: 00000, 11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777, 88888, 99999*" Is this only in the case of the single letter followed by 5 digits-style identifier?

Comment: If lookarounds are supported, the end-part can be something like [`(\d)(?!\1+$)\d{3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/0tqM0c/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
/\b\d{3}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{4}\b|\b\d{2,3} \d{3} \d{3}\b|\b[A-Za-z](\d)(?!\1{4})\d{4}\b/g
```

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/Af6X0H/1)

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` \b\d{3}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{4}\b ``` | Non-word on the left and a word on the right of a zero space character, then 3 digits, then a dash `-`, then 3 digits, then a dash `-`, then 4 digits, then a word on the left and a non-word to the right of a zero space character. |
| ``` | ``` | OR |
| ``` \b\d{2,3} \d{3} \d{3}\b ``` | Non-word on left and a word on the right of a zero space character, then 2 to 3 digits, then a space, then 3 digits, then a space, then 3 digits, then a word on the left and a non-word on the left of a zero space character. |
| ``` | ``` | OR |
| ``` \b[A-Za-z](\d)(?!\1{4})\d{4}\b ``` | Non-word on the left and a word on the right of a zero space character, then a letter (of any case), then a capture group of 1 digit, this will only match if the there ISN'T 4 more of the digit found in the previous capture group, then 4 digits, and finally a word on the left and a non-word on the right of a zero space character. |

A slicker version by The fourth bird wraps everything in `\b(?:`...`)\b` which cuts down on the code size of my RegEx by 11 characters.

```js
/\b(?:\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{2,3} \d{3} \d{3}|[A-Za-z](\d)(?!\1{4})\d{4})\b/g
```

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/vIoD7j/1)

```js
const str = `
987 654 321
10 203 405
A12345
123-456-7890

x00000
888 777-999
111-2222-333
741 852 9630`;

const rgx = /\b\d{3}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{4}\b|\b\d{2,3} \d{3} \d{3}\b|\b[A-Za-z](\d)(?!\1{4})\d{4}\b/g;

console.log(str.match(rgx));
```